# How to properly change elements within Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, wear-os, layout-inflater

I have two pages (Fragments) in my app that each have their own interaction. A long click on either page should toggle the color scheme to black and white and back again. This is accomplished using a separate java class that is called from either page. This works perfectly when run from the second page, but when run from the first page, the second page isn't changed. Here's some of my code, simplified for length:

Page 1:

```
    firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);
    secondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container);

//A bunch of code and then....

    element1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            pm = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pm", false);
            if (pm) {
                performance.PerfModeOff();
                pm = false;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("pm", pm).apply();
            } else {
                performance.PerfModeOn(mContext);
                pm = true;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("pm", pm).apply();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Page 2:

```
        secondView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
    firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container);

//A bunch of code and then...

element2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            pm = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pm", false);
            if (pm) {
                performance.PerfModeOff();
                pm = false;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("pm", pm).apply();
            } else {
                performance.PerfModeOn(mContext);
                pm = true;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("pm", pm).apply();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The class that's changing the colors:

```
public Performance(View firstView, View secondView,LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    mfirstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container,false);
    msecondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container,true);

    uparrow= (ImageView) firstView.findViewById(R.id.UpArrow);
//**A lot of lines like above 

    public void PerfModeOn(Context context) {

mfirstView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
msecondView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

uparrow.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkTint)));

//** More lines to change colors

public void PerfModeOff() {
//**Lines to change colors back
```

Of course if you need to see some more code, just let me know. What can I do to fix this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your second view never changes because `PerfModeOn()` calls `mfirstView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` naively. You need to pass which view to set the background of, so it sets the correct background.

In other words, your first view will only ever be the view changed because of how explicit you were when setting the background.

An alternative would be:

```
public void perfModeOn(Context context, View viewToSetBackgroundOf) {
    viewToSetBackgroundOf.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    ...
}
```

An even better approach would be to implement an `OnLongClickListener` that both of your views use. Then you get which view was clicked in your `onLongClick()` method. Then a simple if statement on which view was clicked, and set the background of the opposite view. This would get rid of your redundant code, and some unneeded methods.

Comment: If I don't use inflaters and provide my views as arguments in PerfModeOn and PerfModeOff, like you suggest, I have the same problem: The first page still won't change the text or images on the second page. There's a lot of strange behavior too, depending on the order of which page I LongClick. Any other thoughts?